# How to search a word in a file using PowerShell script

Tags: full-text-search, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

I have a list of 350 folders and each folder has a file Access log. I need to search all 350 files under all 350 folders for a name "Hound" and display the name of the folders which contain the name "Hound" in their access log file. 
Below is my code, can someone help me with what should be added here to get the desired output, please?

```
   #List all the folders in C:\testfolder
   $folders = (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\testfolder" | Where-Object{$_.Attributes -eq "Directory"} | Select Fullname)

   #looping all folders
   Foreach ($folder in $folders)
   {

   #Here I need to look for the word "Hound" inside the Access.log file and if the word is there, it should display the name of the $folder which has the word
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fairly basic way to do this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path d:\testfolder -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "Hound"
```

If you need to make sure that only files called `access.log` are searched then specify a filter:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path d:\testfolder -Include "access.log" -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "Hound"
```

Comment: @CodeX = you know you can mark solutions as correct (see tick button at left of this answer) and upvote then? That's how our site works, People are more likely to assist you if they see a track record of marking answers as accepted.

Comment: i did that, but it says once I earn 15 reputations, then only I cn publicly mark answers.

Comment: @CodeX - try now...I gave you a +1

Comment: Done @kev :) 

Thank u so much :)

Comment: Doesn't this only find filenames for having the word 'hound'? The OP asked how to search *inside* the files

Comment: @Fandango68 - no, it actually searches inside the file. The contents of the file are piped from `Get-ChildItem` into `Select-String`. Just sanity checked it because you had me worried :)