# Review SSRS Log Files using Powershell

Tags: powershell, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, powerbi

We have to regularly examine log files of our PowerBI Server for any errors:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Report Server\PBIRS\LogFiles
```

Can we scan the entire file using either powershell or any utility which will list any issues which has been logged?

We want to automate this, scan log files regularly, if any issues/errors r seen in log files then email should be sent.

Currently we are doing this manually.

Comment: Scan the file with condition, then based on that do action, have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Like Mahmood said, this is regular programming. Read Input, process rules, Send output. What is your technical issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Answer to your question is **YES.**

WildCard Search:
Look for the `regex expression` for powershell and you can search a specific keyword and define your logic.

Keyword Search:
[How to search a word in a file using PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520368/how-to-search-a-word-in-a-file-using-powershell-script)